# How do I install Ubunte next to Windows?

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

I have Windows 8 installed.  I'd like to install Ubunutu, too, giving me an option to boot into either Windows, or Ubunbtu.

I have resized the Windows partition, leaving 10 GB available for Ubuntu.

On booting with the Ubuntu DVD, it doesn't 'see' Windows.  Says it can't find another OS, do I want to install Ubuntu on the entire disk.

No, I don't want to do that.  I want to install it as a dual-boot system.

Why is Ubuntu not seeing Windows, and is there a workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

After inserting ubuntu live DVD you can see windows drive in NTFS format. All the drives listed in NTFS format are windows rest will either unassigned or EXT format(which is ubuntu).

steps to do dual boot windows & ubuntu. Assuming you windows is working fine and a separate 10GB drive works fine for ubuntu.
[image: install ubuntu]

[image: continue]

[image]

after selecting something else checkbox you get a list of drives don't touch the files with NTFS format as they are windows.

Select the 10 GB drive which you created, in that make 8GB for /(root) and the rest for swap.

And this worked for me. 
But sometime after restart the windows may not be visible for GRUB that can be solved don't panic.